# Flutter_tflite : failed precondiction

Tags: flutter, interpreter, tflite

I'm using flutter_tfite package to load a tflite model in my flutter App using interpreter.
I get this error when I press predict bouton:

```
Another exception was thrown: Bad state: failed precondition
E/tflite  ( 4325): tensorflow/lite/kernels/expand_dims.cc:40 axis >= 0 was not true.
E/tflite  ( 4325): Node number 0 (EXPAND_DIMS) failed to prepare.
```

it seems like input dimension are not compatoble with the model despite I used the same input when I tested the model before transfor it into tflite format.

in the UI I get nothing happend when pressing predict bouton while in my terminal I get the previous error.
Someone could help fixing it
this is the portion of code related to this issue :

```
Interpreter? interpreter;
  List<double> inputData = [];

  Future<Interpreter> loadModel() async {
  final interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions()
    ..threads = 2; // Spécifiez le nombre de threads souhaité pour l'interpréteur
  final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(
    'assets/model.tflite',
    options: interpreterOptions,
  );
  this.interpreter = interpreter;
  return interpreter;
}
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel().then((interpreter) {
      setState(() {
        this.interpreter = interpreter;
      });
    });

  }
  List<double> outputData = [];

  void runModel() {
  var inputData = [temperature, humidity, precipitation, pH, nitrogen, potassium, phosphorus];
  final outputList = List<double>.filled(22, 0.0);
  interpreter?.run(inputData, outputList);
  // Afficher les données d'entrée dans la console
  print('Input data: $inputData');
  setState(() {
    outputData = outputList;
  });
  interpreter?.close();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Crop Recommender'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                nitrogen = double.parse(value);
                inputData[4] = nitrogen;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Nitrogen',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                phosphorus = double.parse(value);
                inputData[6] = phosphorus;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phosphorus',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                potassium = double.parse(value);
                inputData[6] = phosphorus;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Potassium',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                temperature = double.parse(value);
                inputData[0] = temperature;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Temperature',
              ),
              
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                humidity = double.parse(value);
                inputData[1] = humidity;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Humidity',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                pH = double.parse(value);
                inputData[3] = pH;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'pH',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                precipitation = double.parse(value);
                inputData.add(precipitation);
                inputData[2] = precipitation;
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Precipitation',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: runModel,
              child: const Text('Get Crop Recommendation'),
            ),
```

Comment: were you able to solve this error?